# Linux C++ program crashes with St9bad_alloc after map gets very huge

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, dictionary, bad-alloc

I am running a C++ program that involving building inverted index on red hat linux 64 bits. My invert index is defined as `map<unsigned long long int, map<int,int> > invertID;` and I got this error where it crashes randomly, with `what():  St9bad_alloc`.Each time of the crash is different. Sometimes, I got 100,000,000 keys and it's still running a while more. Sometimes, about 80,000,000 keys and it already yell out the error.

Googling around, I found that this error may come from `new`, but taking a look at my code, I am not using any `new` keyword, yet, I have such memory allocation with map. I keep on inserting in the key/value pair in each iteration. So I decided some experiment with `try` `catch` statement.

In fact, here is the critical part of the code and output:

```
    map<unsigned long long int, map<int,int> >::iterator mainMapIt = invertID.find(ID);
    if (mainMapIt != invertID.end()){
    //if this ImageID key exists in InvID sub-map
        map<int,int> M = mainMapIt->second; // THIS IS LINE 174.
        map<int,int>::iterator subMapIt = M.find(imageID);
        if (subMapIt != M.end()){
        //increment the number of this ImageID key
            ++invertID[ID][imageID];
        }
        else{
        //add ImageID key with value 1 into the InvertID
            try{
                invertID[ID][imageID] = 1;
                ++totalPushBack;
            }catch (bad_alloc ba){
                cout << "CAUGHT 1: invertID[" << ID << "][" << imageID << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
    //create the first empty map with the key as image ID with value 1 and put it in implicitly to the invertID
        try{
            invertID[ID][imageID] = 1;
        }catch (bad_alloc ba){
            cout << "CAUGHT 2: invertID[" << ID << "][" << imageID << endl;
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
...
CAUGHT 2: invertID[21959247897][3856
CAUGHT 2: invertID[38022506156][3856
CAUGHT 2: invertID[29062506144][3856
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  St9bad_alloc
```

I see that when I tried to insert new key, the error is thrown. However, I got a bit more surprise that `St9bad_alloc` is still being thrown after I cover the key insertion part with `try` `catch` block. I did a little backtrace and here is the result:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x000000344ac30265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000344ac31d10 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000034510becb4 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00000034510bcdb6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00000034510bcde3 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00000034510bceca in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00000034510bd1d9 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000000000406544 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int> > >::allocate (
    this=0x7fffffffdfc0, __n=1)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/ext/new_allocator.h:88
#8  0x0000000000406568 in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_M_get_node (this=0x7fffffffdfc0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:358
#9  0x0000000000406584 in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_M_create_node (this=0x7fffffffdfc0, __x=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:367
#10 0x00000000004065e3 in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_M_clone_node (this=0x7fffffffdfc0, __x=0x21c082bd0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:381
#11 0x0000000000406634 in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_M_copy (this=0x7fffffffdfc0, __x=0x21c082bd0, __p=0x7fffffffdfc8)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1226
#12 0x00000000004067e9 in std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_Rb_tree (this=0x7fffffffdfc0, __x=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:570
#13 0x0000000000406885 in std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::map (
    this=0x7fffffffdfc0, __x=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:175
#14 0x0000000000403039 in generateInvertID (pathToPF=0x6859a8 "/home/karl/c/000605.pf",
    pathToC=0x38c139ed8 "/home/karl/c/000605.c", imageID=3856)
    at InvertIndexGen.cpp:174
#15 0x0000000000403b46 in generateInvertIDForAllPFAndC () at InvertIndexGen.cpp:254
#16 0x0000000000403d0b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe448) at InvertIndexGen.cpp:47
(gdb)
```

At #14, InvertIndexGen.cpp:174, in my code above, this is where it crashed:

```
map<int,int> M = mainMapIt->second; // THIS IS LINE 174.
```

It seems that when I call `->second`, a copy of the respective map has to be created. This should be the reason of `St9bad_alloc` as well.

But in this case, is there anything I can do here? After all, `invertID.max_size()` return 18446744073709551615, and I am using about 100 million keys only. I also see it from `top`, that my program uses only 10% of memory. (we got 128GB RAM)

What are some of the measures I should use against this error? I see some of my senior colleagues are doing this as well, and they report that when their invert index starts to grow more than 70-80% of memory in `top`, the program starts to go haywire. But my program uses only 10%, so what's going on here? What are some of the things we can do to prevent this error?

EDIT: some comments suggest me to check with `ulimit`, so here it is:

```
-bash-3.2$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1056768
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1056768
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: You should check your process limits (start with the global limits by using the `ulimit` command). The memory might be limited some way.

Comment: max_size is a purely theoretical value and doesnt have anything to do with the real amount of memory. You should dig deeper into your memory usage, compare rss,swap,vsize of the process, investigate possible ulimits and actual values to new, and of course looking at the source code of the throw wont hurt too.

Comment: Here's my ulimit:
 -bash-3.2$ ulimit -a
 `core file size`          (blocks, -c) 0
 `data seg size`           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
 `scheduling priority`             (-e) 0
 `file size`               (blocks, -f) unlimited
 `pending signals`                 (-i) 1056768
 `max locked memory`       (kbytes, -l) 32
 `max memory size`         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
 `open files`                      (-n) 1024
 `pipe size`            (512 bytes, -p) 8
 `POSIX message queues`     (bytes, -q) 819200
 `real-time priority`              (-r) 0
 `stack size`              (kbytes, -s) 10240

Comment: `cpu time`               (seconds, -t) unlimited
 `max user processes`              (-u) 1056768
 `virtual memory`          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
 `file locks`                      (-x) unlimited

Comment: I have updated the question with ulimit

Comment: when you say 100 million keys,that is from invertID?  what about the value of each element (the submap) in invertID?  how big is that?  128gb, is it safe to assume then that you are on 64-bit machine running 64-bit linux?  when you use **top** what does the **virt** say?

Comment: Yes, 100 million keys is for the invertID map alone. For each sub-map, `map<int,int>`, there are very few keys - there should be about 1-20 keys. Most of the time, it is < 10. Not much. I have also counted the total number of inserting a new key into any sub-map `map<int,int>` as well, and by the time, it crashes, I got invertID size of 126,252,979 with all sub-maps size combined: 1,319,366,634.

Yes, the OS is 64 bits, or else, we won't be able to run program that takes 80-90 GB in our server.

Comment: @thang: it depends. As we keep on inserting keys into the invert index, virt keeps on increasing. virt says 17.2g for my program by the last time it crashed.

Comment: hmm i guess it's not out of memory then.  i wonder if you ran over memory (like writing to a dangling pointer or something) somewhere else...

Comment: one thing you can try is to use memtrack http://www.almostinfinite.com/memtrack.html.  see if it will give you new insight...

Comment: and also back trace up the stack and see what the parameter is in thsi call **0x00000034510bd1d9 in operator new(unsigned long) ()**

Comment: In my program, I don't use pointer variables in the processing part so no referencing or dereferencing there. The only part where there are some pointers are those at iterators and c_str function where I need const char* for some function. But there are no modification via pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
map<int,int> M = mainMapIt->second; // THIS IS LINE 174.
```

does a copy of your second.

```
map<int,int>& M = mainMapIt->second; // THIS IS LINE 174.
```

would at least help to avoid this copy.

Answer (score 1):

`map<int,int> M = mainMapIt->second; // THIS IS LINE 174.` 
This line will cause a unnessary map copy, and memory allocations.
Change to reference would help.
`map<int,int> & M = mainMapIt->second; // THIS IS LINE 174.`